# Nested virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Given the following situation:

```
struct A
{
  const float x;
  const float y;

  A(float x, float y)
  : x{x}, y{y} {}
};

class B
{
  public:
    B(const float& floating)
    : floating{floating} {}

    virtual float foo_x() const = 0;
    virtual float foo_y() const = 0;

    virtual A foo() const
    {
      return A(foo_x(), foo_y());
    }

  protected:
    const float& floating;
};

class C : public B
{
  public:
    C(const int* integer, const float& floating)
    : B{floating}, integer{integer} {}

    virtual float foo_x() const override
    {
      return static_cast<float>(*integer) + floating + 1.0f;
    }

    virtual float foo_y() const override
    {
      return static_cast<float>(*integer) - floating - 2.0f;
    }
  private:
    const int* integer;
};

int main()
{
  float F{1.0f};
  int I{1};

  C object(&I, F);

  A res{object.foo()};
}
```

is there anything wrong with the definition of `foo()`? The snippet above produces the expected result (`res` holding `3` and `-2`), but a similar setup in a bigger project is producing some unexpected results upon calling `foo()`, while giving the correct output if I call separately `foo_x()` and `foo_y()` from `C` (I'm sorry I've not been able to reproduce the bug in a minimal way).

Am I invoking some undefined behavior by calling `foo_x()` and `foo_y()` inside the definition of `foo()` in `B`? Seems to me that, as `foo()` is ultimately called by `C`, the vtable should be resolved correctly, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Code smell with `const float& floating;`, since the lifespan of the object's member variable is tied to the argument passed in.

Comment: is `foo()` being called from a constructor in the larger project by any chance?

Comment: If this code does not cause the issue from your larger program, then it's not a sufficient minimal reproducible example.  My gut tells me that you might be calling `foo()` from a constructor in a base class, which is definitely going to give you problems.  Focus on capturing the subtleties of your larger program.

Comment: @Eljay thanks! Fixing that smell made the actual bug emerge!

Comment: @Frank it wasn't. If you're curious: I was passing an rvalue to the constructor of B at some point, and in one case it was being killed by the compiler before its use, in another one not.

Comment: @uhwo glad you found it! Usual grumblings: `const` members and reference members are nothing but trouble and best left out of any design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I invoking some undefined behavior by calling foo_x() and foo_y() inside the definition of foo() in B?

No. This is well defined and works the way you expect it to, as long as all regular preconditions for calling virtual functions are met.

The easiest mistake to make with regard to these preconditions is that the subclass, `C` in this case, must be fully constructed before the `virtual` call is made.